# React Native post request causes infinite loop when displaying array

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, mobile

I am navigating to this 'History' tab from a side menu in React Native Navigation. Got a username for which I get all the 'bookings' made, but I can see in the warning tab that there are countless requests being made even after the component has been mounted, so there's an infinite loop probably caused by setState. Where should I call getHistory(), as in to make only one request, unless of course the component is reloaded. Thank you!

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            loggedUser: 'none',
            bookingsInfo: []
        }
    }

    getData = async () => {
        try {
          const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('loggedUser')
          if(value !== null) {
            this.setState({
                loggedUser: value
            })
          }
        } catch(e) {
            console.error(e);
        }
    }

    getHistory() {
            fetch('https://porsche.e-twow.uk/reactnative/istoric.php', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    Accept: 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    username: this.state.loggedUser
                })
            })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
                this.setState({
                    bookingsInfo: data
                });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getData();
    }

    render() {
        this.getHistory();
        return (
            <View style={styles.view}>
                <ScrollView style={styles.scrollView}>
                    {
                        this.getHistory()
                    }
                    {
                        this.state.bookingsInfo ? this.state.bookingsInfo.map((item, index) => {
                            return (
                                <View style={styles.mainButton} key={item.id_scooter}>
                                    <Text style={styles.mainButtonText}>Scooter-ul {item.id_scooter}</Text>
                                    <Text style={styles.mainButtonText}>Data start: {item.start}</Text>
                                    <Text style={styles.mainButtonText}>Data final: {item.end}</Text>
                                </View>
                            )
                        }) : null
                    }
                </ScrollView>

                <Footer/>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably want to move `getHistory` to `componentDidMount`. Never call setState inside the render method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are setting state in render.Calling setState here makes your component a contender for producing infinite loops.
 place getHistory in componentDidMount .

```
  componentDidMount() {
   this.getHistory();
 }
```

Comment: make getHistory arrow function  gethistory=()=>{}